# What is wrong with this code? Isn't the values getting joined to t?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have to merge two sorted linked lists. 
I dont know how but t is not getting incremented. Is there some mistake in the code?

```
Node * p=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)),*t=p;
while(head1!=NULL && head2!=NULL){
    Node * temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(head1->data<=head2->data){
        temp->data=head1->data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        t=temp;

        head1=head1->next;
        t=t->next;
     }
    else{
        temp->data=head2->data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        t=temp;
        t=t->next;
        head2=head2->next;
    }
}
if(head1==NULL){
    t->next=head2;
    printf("%d\n",t->data);
}
else
t->next=head1;


return p;

}
```

3
1
2
3
be the first linked list.

3
4
be the second linked list

output must be:
1 2 3 3 4

I am getting segmentation fault

Comment: *I have to merge two sorted linked lists* `3 1 2 3` is not sorted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please (re)read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not shown how you create the two source lists; you've not explained why you have 6 inputs in the two lists but only expect 5 outputs.  You've not shown the structure definitions, etc.  If you want to merge two lists, you shouldn't have to allocate any extra memory; the two lists already provide all the information you need.

Comment: sorry. First linked list is 1 2 3. not 3 1 2 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge 2 lists, you have several options.

1. You can copy all elements into a new list.
2. You can remove the nodes from the existing list and put it into the new list.

What you do is none of this.

You start with option 1:

```
while(head1!=NULL && head2!=NULL){
    Node * temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(head1->data<=head2->data){
        temp->data=head1->data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        t=temp;

        head1=head1->next;
        t=t->next;
     }
    else{
        temp->data=head2->data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        t=temp;
        t=t->next;
        head2=head2->next;
    }
}
```

Hint:
You could improve your code by extracting identical instructions from the `if else` blocks and only write them once after the `else` block:

```
while (head1 != NULL && head2 != NULL) {
    Node * temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (head1->data <= head2->data) {
        temp->data = head1->data;   
        head1 = head1->next;
    }
    else {
        temp->data = head2->data;
        head2 = head2->next;
    }

    // Now link the new node:
    t->next = temp;  // <<==== Linking fixed.
    t = t->next;
}
```

Also note that your linking of the new node was broken. You lost the link from `t` to the next node.

But there is another problem:

After you reach the end of one of the lists, you stop copying.
You simply add the remaining list at once to your new list:

```
if(head1==NULL){
    t->next=head2;
    printf("%d\n",t->data);
}
else
    t->next=head1;
```

This means you have no copy, but each of the remaining nodes is rechable via 2 lists.

For the old list this means, the first nodes are exclusively linked via that list but the other nodes have 2 references.

As soon as you start manipulating one of the lists, these nodes could be deleted in one list. Then there is still a link from the other list pointing to the first of these nodes. 
This causes illegal memory access and undefined behaviour when you access the node via the remaining list. This can eventually cause a segmentation faul.

You should copy all pointers. Not stop in the middle of the task.